# Converting multiple records from Hive table into a nested JSON

Tags: java, json, hive

I have a table structure like this in hive:

```
id  Name    Age
1    A      26
1    B      26
```

I want to convert these records into a nested JSON corresponding to the id i.e. for every id , my code should combine the records against it into a JSON object.

Kindly help.

Comment: Do you want the output as e.g. `{"id" : 1, "members": ["A":26, "B":26]}` ?

Comment: ya mattin, something like this only..

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `Name` and `Age` together into a struct using the built in `named_struct` function, e.g:

```
named_struct("Name", Name, "Age", Age)
```

However in order to aggregate these together by common `id` you would need an aggregation function. None of the built-in aggregation functions in Hive provide the functionality you require. This means you will probably need to write a custom Aggregation function (UDAF) in order to meet your goal. The function would be used like:

```
select id, custom_aggregation_function(named_struct("Name", Name, "Age", Age)) from table group by id;
```

For more information on writing your own UDAF, look here 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GenericUDAFCaseStudy

Alternatively, you could look for other third party implementations of the UDAFs you need.

Have a look at the `collect` and `to_json` UDFs from Brickhouse https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki